# Beginner question, how to combine x and y ticks from 2 plots on a shared x and y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to get x and y ticks from 2 plots and share it on the x and y axis. With one plot it works

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
from datetime import datetime

v1 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-15T23:45:51.159618277Z")
v2 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-16T23:49:51.159618277Z")
v3 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-17T22:25:46.638699435Z")
t_time_values2 = [v1, v2, v3]
datenums = md.date2num(t_time_values2)
y = [30, 15, 45]

# plot lines
ax = plt.gca()
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.plot(datenums, y, label="line 1")
ax.set_xticks(datenums)
ax.set_yticks(y)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot1]

But now I try to combine 2 plots, and each x and y tick(from the plot) should be visible on the common x and y axis

I try it with this code, but unfortunately I can not merge the ticks from the 2 plots

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
from datetime import datetime

v1 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-15T23:45:51.159618277Z")
v2 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-16T23:49:51.159618277Z")
v3 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-17T22:25:46.638699435Z")
t_time_values1 = [v1, v2, v3]
datenums1 = md.date2num(t_time_values1)
y1 = [30, 15, 45]

#Plot2
v4 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-15T05:45:51.159618277Z")
v5 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-16T05:49:51.159618277Z")
v6 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-17T02:25:46.638699435Z")
t_time_values2 = [v4, v5, v6]
datenums2 = md.date2num(t_time_values2)
y2 = [78, 25, 55]

# plot lines
ax = plt.gca()
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.plot(datenums1, y1, label="line 1")
plt.plot(datenums2, y2, label="line 2")

ax.set_xticks(datenums1)
ax.set_xticks(datenums2)
ax.set_yticks(y1)
ax.set_yticks(y2)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see how [`ax.set_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) and [`ax.set_yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html) work.

You are getting the current output because of your code: it is explicitly setting the x-ticks according to *datenums2* because how you have asked it to at *line number 28*: `ax.set_xticks(datenums2)`.
This is undoing the expected result from the line written just before that, which is *ax.set_xticks(datenums1)*.

Similar thing is happening with `ax.set_yticks`: it's only plotting yticks using *y2*.

There are different ways to handle this issue :

1. Let matplotlib take care of the tick labels and positions:

[image]
2. Define only y-ticks' locations and let maplotlib take care of y-ticks' labels, x-ticks' locations and their labels:
[image]
3. Define both x-ticks' and y-ticks' locations and let maplotlib take care of x-ticks' and y-ticks' labels.
[image]
*I am using different time but the dates are the same as provided in the question, please see the code below:*

**4. The best way to arrange xticks would be to properly format x-tick labels and let matplotlib take care of y-ticks:**

[image]
**Code for figure 1**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
from datetime import datetime

v1 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-15T23:45:51")
v2 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-16T23:49:51")
v3 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-17T22:25:46")
t_time_values1 = [v1, v2, v3]
datenums1 = md.date2num(t_time_values1)
y1 = [30, 15, 45]

#Plot2
v4 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-15T05:45:51")
v5 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-16T05:49:51")
v6 = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-17T02:25:46")
t_time_values2 = [v4, v5, v6]
datenums2 = md.date2num(t_time_values2)
y2 = [78, 25, 55]

# plot lines
ax = plt.gca()
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.plot(datenums1, y1, label="line 1")
plt.plot(datenums2, y2, label="line 2")

# Code above this comment will remain same for figure 2 and 3

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Code for figure 2:**

```
# Add this in the code for figure 1
ax.set_yticks(y1 + y2)
```

*y1 + y2* creates a list from the elements of *y1* and *y2*.

**Code for figure 3:**

```
# Add these lines in the code for figure 1
ax.set_xticks(datenums1.tolist() + datenums2.tolist())
ax.set_yticks(y1 + y2)
```

*datenums1* and *datenums2* are numpy arrays, so if we try *datenums1 + datenums2*, it will just give another numpy array by doing an element-wise addition. That's why, we convert them to list first to get a list of x-ticks' locations.

**Code for figure 4:**

```
.
.
.
# plot lines
ax = plt.gca()

# xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

plt.plot(datenums1, y1, label="line 1")
plt.plot(datenums2, y2, label="line 2")

# Formatting of xticklabels 
xticks = datenums1.tolist() + datenums2.tolist()
labels = t_time_values1 + t_time_values2

def format_xlabels(x):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
    label = x.strftime(fmt)
    label = label.rstrip("0") # Optional
    label = label.rstrip(".") # Optional
    return(label)

xlabels = [format_xlabels(i) for i in labels]
ax.set_xticks(xticks, labels=xlabels)

xlabels = ax.get_xticklabels()
plt.setp(xlabels, rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout() # Important for xtick labels to show up in the figure
plt.show()
```

Please check the function `my_format_function` from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter) which I used to create the function `format_xlabels` in the code above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! This is the nicest answer I habe ever received on stackoverflow. I didn't know that I can merge the x values list!.

Comment: Figure 4 is exactly what I need. Because when matpotlib takes care of the x axes the seconds are always 0. e.g. 2022-10-15 12:00:00:000, it is too "inaccurate"